# 1080p playback on external monitor

Tags: high-definition, 1080p

My system (netbook) specs:

1.6 GHz dual core atom N2600
2 GB DDR3 RAM
Integrated GMA3600 GPU
Win 7 Professional 32 Bit
Daum Pot Player V-1.5

The issue:

I downloaded a 1.33 GB sized 1920 x 1080 HD documentary (file extension: mp4) and it plays without a hitch using pot player. However, when I connected an external display (an LED Full HD 24" monitor) using D-Sub, the video plays fine but the player controls become very unresponsive. For instance, it takes about 40 seconds to exit full screen while playing.

I tried:

Installed/updated all the latest monitor drivers
Updated the VGA drivers for GMA3600
No other programs ran while the video played, with most unwanted services and background processes disabled/killed.
CPU usage goes only up to 49% when the video plays

Question:

What may I do in order to improve the player response/video playback experience?
Do I need to play with (or change) Pot Player's default video decoders, etc?

Comment: have you tried other media players? VLC? Media Player Classic?

Comment: [MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) supports hardware acceleration.

Comment: thats strange.  The monitor should have no effect on the video. The signal is the same no matter what it is connected to.

Comment: @Keltari: You're right, and that's exactly my reason to wonder; and ask here.

Comment: @Logman & Louis: Update: Yes, I've tried those two players and they stutter even on my native 10.1" display. Pot Player, on the other hand, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have it fixed now and for the information to all, I changed the default video renderer from EVR to Madshi. The following is the snapshot. 1080p videos now play like honey in a cup of milk: Smooth!!

[image: Snapshot]